# Copy child elements under a different element

Tags: xslt

I have an xml file in following format

```
<root>
<entities>
    <entity>
        <entity_name></entity_name>
        <entity_id></entity_id>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <entity_name></entity_name>
        <entity_id></entity_id>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <entity_name></entity_name>
        <entity_id></entity_id>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

I am trying to convert it into following xml format using xslt.

```
<root>
 <entity_name></entity_name>
 <entity_id></entity_id>

 <entity_name></entity_name>
 <entity_id></entity_id>

 <entity_name></entity_name>
 <entity_id></entity_id>
```

I am new to XSLT and have been trying to get to the solution since many hours.
Kindly suggest and if I could get a few good references to learn XSLT, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by building upon the standard XSLT Identity Transform

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own, it will just copy all your elements as-is. So, what you need to do is add extra templates that match you **entities** and **entity** elements, but just output their children without actually copying the elements themselves.

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="entities|entity">
         <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XSLT

```
<root>
   <entities>
      <entity>
         <entity_name/>
         <entity_id/>
      </entity>
      <entity>
         <entity_name/>
         <entity_id/>
      </entity>
      <entity>
         <entity_name/>
         <entity_id/>
      </entity>
   </entities>
</root>
```

The following is output

```
<root>
   <entity_name></entity_name>
   <entity_id></entity_id>
   <entity_name></entity_name>
   <entity_id></entity_id>
   <entity_name></entity_name>
   <entity_id></entity_id>
</root>
```